# Replacing the innerHTML of an HTML p tag- event not firing

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, dom-events, mousemove

I have the following JS function, which I am using to detect when the cursor is hovering over a particular image on an HTML5 canvas:

```
function cursorOverAssetsBox(mouseX, mouseY){
    if((mouseX >= assetsDescriptionBox.img_x && mouseX <= assetsDescriptionBox.img_x + assetsDescriptionBox.img_width) &&
    (mouseY <= assetsDescriptionBox.img_y && mouseY >= assetsDescriptionBox.img_y - assetsDescriptionBox.img_height))
    document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = tips[34];
    console.log(tips[34]);
}
```

The function works correctly, but for some reason, the line

```
document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = tips[34];
```

doesn't appear to be firing...

'tipsParagraph' is the ID I have given to an HTML `<p></p>` tag in the `<body></body>` of my HTML. 'tips' is an array, each element of which contains some text.

I want to display the text stored in position 34 of that array whenever the cursor is in the location specified by my if statement. I know that the function works, because the line `console.log(tips[34]);` is displaying the contents of that element of the array in the console whenever the cursor is in that location. But for some reason, the text in the paragraph is not updated to display the contents of that array element.

Can anyone figure out why this is?

I am calling the function from within the `mousemove` function of a local copy of the KineticJS library. I'm using a local copy of the library, as there are a couple of slight adjustments I wanted to make to its functionality, such as this one. The 'mousemove' function currently looks like this:

```
_mousemove: function(evt) {
    this._setUserPosition(evt);
    var dd = Kinetic.DD;
    var obj = this.getIntersection(this.getUserPosition());
    getMousePosition(evt);
    document.getElementById('mouseLocation').innerHTML = "mouseX = " + evt.clientX + ". mouseY = " + evt.clientY;

    /*Add an if statement, so that cursorOverAssetsBox function is only called when the cursor's y value is greater than
        400. This will improve performance, as the code will only check if it needs to call the function when the cursor is
        below that line. */
    if(mouseY >= 400){
        cursorOverAssetsBox(mouseX, mouseY);
    }

    /*Write an if statement that says, "if 'draggingImage' variable is set to true, check the x & y of that image to see if
        it's over its description box- if it is, do something, if not, don't", if 'draggingImage' variable is not set
        to true, don't check.*/
    //cursorOverAssetsBox(mouseX, mouseY);

    if(obj) {
        var shape = obj.shape;
        if(shape) {
            if((!dd || !dd.moving) && obj.pixel[3] === 255 && (!this.targetShape || this.targetShape._id !== shape._id)) {
                if(this.targetShape) {
                    this.targetShape._handleEvent('mouseout', evt, shape);
                    this.targetShape._handleEvent('mouseleave', evt, shape);
                }
                shape._handleEvent('mouseover', evt, this.targetShape);
                shape._handleEvent('mouseenter', evt, this.targetShape);
                this.targetShape = shape;
            }
            else {
                shape._handleEvent('mousemove', evt);
            }
        }
    }
    /*
     * if no shape was detected, clear target shape and try
     * to run mouseout from previous target shape
     */
    else if(this.targetShape && (!dd || !dd.moving)) {
        this.targetShape._handleEvent('mouseout', evt);
        this.targetShape._handleEvent('mouseleave', evt);
        this.targetShape = null;
    }

    // start drag and drop
    if(dd) {
        dd._startDrag(evt);
    }
}
```

Comment: which is the browser used

Comment: I'm using Firefox, and viewing the console output in Firebug... I wouldn't have thought that this would make a difference to what's happening though?

Comment: can try changing the `p` element to a `div` for testing purpose? I not seeing any problem with the code

Comment: Perhaps you could make a JSFiddle of it to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: The `p` element is not the problem- the text it displays is updated correctly when I click on an image rather than just mouseover (different function). I tried changing it to a `div`, but that breaks some other code that I have in my page...

Comment: I tried putting a JSFiddle together, but it doesn't appear to want to show the canvas in the result panel